# What is time complexity of `last` method for List in scala?

Tags: scala, list

What is the time complexity of the `last` method for List in Scala?

```
scala> var list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> list.last
res0: Int = 5
```

Does scala iterate through all list to get the last element *(O(n))* or the `List` has a pointer to the last element *(O(1))*?

Comment: Well... `List` in scala is a forward-linked-list. So `.last`, `+` (anything which has to do with last element) have time-complexity of `O(n)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the source it is O(n)

```
  override /*TraversableLike*/
  def last: A = {
    if (isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException
    var these = this
    var nx = these.tail
    while (!nx.isEmpty) {
      these = nx
      nx = nx.tail
    }
    these.head
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want constant-time access to the last element consider using `IndexedSeq`. The `last` complexity is always O(1)